# Java Regex expression (4digits followed by 2 zeros)

Tags: java, regex

This one's gonna be simple.

Writing a java program where user enters 4 digits, followed by 2 zeros.
There's no space in between.

ex. "123400", "454500", "988900"

This is my code:

```
String password = in.nextLine();    

Pattern Pass = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{4}.[0]{2}.$");
Matcher matPASS = Pass.matcher(password);
```

It's checking wether the expression is correct. How would I rewrite the expression in ("")?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: If it's simple what stopping from your making an attempt and asking specific question?

Comment: I just posted my code which has an issue.

Comment: Good response, because whatever I do, it seems that eclipse isn't recognizing 4 digits and 2 zeros

Comment: Remove the `.`s.

Comment: Didn't work Andy!

Comment: Please specify what exactly happened when you say it "didn't work". Was there an error returned? The pattern `^\d{4}00$` should fit your criteria.

Comment: lose both the dots (.) from your expression.

Comment: No, it fails to match it. when I input a number it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JBone, removing both dots did work the matcher.

```
Pattern Pass = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{4}[0]{2}$");
```